# How to restore a blob snapshot to a managed disk

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-aks, azure-disk

I'm currently migrating from ACS to AKS.

I can snapshot the existing storage blobs and restore those to different storage blobs anywhere in Azure.

So far I can't see any efficient way how to restore a blob-snapshot to managed disks (which are mandatory storages in AKS).

What's the royal way to do so since the command

```
az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas
```

does not work for disks?

Comment: Have you checked the doc on migrating from ACS to AKS? It might help you with all the steps needed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/acs-aks-migration

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Migrating from Azure Container Service (ACS) to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/acs-aks-migration), as the comment suggests, you can take a look at the document.

For [disk migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/acs-aks-migration#migrating-persistent-volumes), I think the disk should be the persist volume disk, you can snapshot the disk and create a new disk from the snapshot as the persist volume in AKS. Add the disk as a persist volume in AKS, you can follow the steps in [Manually create and use a volume with Azure disks in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume).

In addition, you need to quiesce writes to the application and shutdown it. Or it would miss data in the migration. Check the application after the migration if it works as you expect.